# animate a dark overlay concurrent to a CABasicAnimation

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, quartz-graphics, caanimation

I'm attempting to recreate the boilerplate animation:

```
UIView.transitionFromView(aView, toView: bView, duration: 1.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromRight, completion: nil)
```

Which flips a view and adds a dark overlay effect while animating to add perspective to the animation. I've figured out how to flip the animation using CABasicAnimation but have been unable to add a flawless overlay.

I've been looking around the internet for a while now and have attempted several things including adding an overlay UIView prior to the animation and reducing the layer's opacity which hasn't worked.

Here's what I have so far

Tap Gesture calls:

```
func handleTap(){
    if currentAnimation == 0 {
        animateLayerAcrossDiagonalAxis(imageView.layer, r: CGFloat(M_PI / 2), x: 0, y: 1, z: 0, m34: 1.0 / (imageView.layer.frame.size.height - 10), keyPath: "transform", removedOnCompletion: false)
        }
    }
```

my animation needs to run twice so I assign a different image for the front or backside:

```
func toggleFront(){
    if front == true {
        front = false
    }
    else {
        front = true
    }

}
```

this is my function where I'd like to create the dark overlay

```
func animateLayerAcrossDiagonalAxis(layer :CALayer, r: CGFloat, x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, z: CGFloat, m34:CGFloat, keyPath:String, removedOnCompletion rOC:Bool){
    // store the layer's original values
    let original = layer.transform
    //transform based on set matrix
    let transform = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
    transform.delegate = self
    transform.duration = 2.0
    transform.fromValue = original as? AnyObject
    // so we have KVC upon completion
    transform.removedOnCompletion = rOC
    layer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(layer.transform, CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DIdentity, r, x, y, z))
    layer.transform.m34 = m34
    //m34 is the attribute of the matrix that sets perception
    layer.addAnimation(transform, forKey: keyPath)
}
```

and here I'm calling the function again to flip the image over completely

```
override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
    // makes sure the animation only flips twice
    if   anim == imageView.layer.animationForKey("transform") {
        // toggles the front and back image
        if front == true {
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "2")
        }
        else {
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "1")
        }
      toggleFront()
animateLayerAcrossDiagonalAxis(imageView.layer, r: -CGFloat(M_PI / 2), x: 0, y: 1, z: 0, m34: 1.0 / (imageView.layer.frame.size.height - 10), keyPath: "transformBack", removedOnCompletion: false)
    }
}
```

Comment: And what about this isn't working?

Comment: I'm sorry I should have been more specific: this works fine. But I'm trying to understand how to add dark overlay to add perspective to the animation.